# awk to add to field based on condition

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I am trying to add adjust `$2` in the ouput by adding `+1` if the original value from file that was used in `$2` had a `-` in it. Line 2 of `in` is an example of this. In my current `awk` I my logic is not correct as I am looking in `$2` and splitting on the `-` and storing the values in 'array' if there is one and keeping the count of the fields in `num`. Based on the count in `num` I print the output of the split or no split. In my actual data there may be hundreds of lines but always the same format. Seems close but not quite there. Thank you :).

**in**

```
chr15 91543131 AAW33B
chr8 100493900-100493909 SBSA
```

**awk**

```
awk '{num=split($2,array,"[ -]");if(num==3){print $1,$2-1,$2,$3};if(num==4){print $1,array[1],array[2],array[2],$3}}' in | column -t
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr15   91543130    91543131    AAW33B
chr8    100493900   100493909   SBSA
```

Comment: What is your actual input? Do you have `---` or just `-`? Is the `--- num==3??? ---` part of your input?

Comment: it seems to me that you created a new field on line one since it did *not* contain a dash; you also split line two based on the dash?

Comment: If your input is space-delimited, you could set `FS` to `/[ -]/` and then look at `NF` to determine what your output should be.

Comment: Sorry the `---` and `?` is not part of the input, it was just to show what I thought `num` was. Thank you :).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ input you are trying to parse. It looks like you want to produce a bed file, starting from some sort of weird vcf-like format, but I can't tell if you don't show us actual lines from the file.

Comment: I made the edit and yes you are correct in that it is a bed from a weird vcf format. Thank you :).

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this input:

```
chr15 91543131 AAW33B
chr8 100493900-100493909 SBSA
```

We can simply have `awk` split input based on `/[ -]/` (i. e. a space *or* a `-` as a field separator).  We can also just give `awk` a tab as an output field separator which means we no longer need `column -t`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ -]"; OFS="\t" } NF==3 { print $1, $2 - 1, $2, $3 } NF==4 { print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' input
chr15   91543130    91543131    AAW33B
chr8    100493900   100493909   SBSA
```

Alternatively, we could leave the field separator alone, and just look to see whether the second field contains a `-`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } $2 !~ /-/ { print $1, $2 - 1, $2, $3 } $2 ~ /-/ { split( $2, a, "-" ); print $1, a[1], a[2], $3 }' input
chr15   91543130    91543131    AAW33B
chr8    100493900   100493909   SBSA
```